# Save metadata while converting video to images FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata

When I convert a video to its constituent images (`ffmpeg -i video.MOV img1%03d.png`), ffmpeg drops all the metadata. How would I save the metadata while converting? Is there any way to have it also increment the timestamp for each frame?

Comment: PNG can't store the MOV metadata. You could dump it into a text file however. Would that be acceptable? What do you mean by, "increment the timestamp for each frame"?